# Idea 14 - Maven 3 - pass parameters

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am looking for most efficient way to pass parameters to maven through idea 14 (I have just started working with idea).

When I want to compile and deploy my application through maven itself, I just run this command `mvn clean package tomcat7:redeploy -P localhost -Daugage_env=local`.

I dont know, how to pass this parameter `-Daugage_env=local` as default (or how to integrate it with localhost profile, which would be even better).

I did try `maven-projects->myproject->lifecycle->`right click on compile and create custom compile where I changed the `Command line` text to `compile -Daugage_env=local`, but it does not work.

Comment: If I understand correctly the note about integrating the parameter with localhost profile, why not just set the property in pom like `<profile><id>localhost</id><properties><augage_env>local</augage_env></properties></profile>`? In which case it would be automatically set when localhost profile is active

Comment: Glad it worked for you :) I posted the comment as an answer in case you'd like to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define profile specific properties directly in pom.xml like so:

```
<profile>
    <id>localhost</id>
    <properties>
        <augage_env>local</augage_env>
    </properti‌​es>
</profile>
```

More information can be found in [Maven documentation for build profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).